# AWS Outage Reroute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I am stuck on a possible implementation for a problem I am facing in AWS.

I have multiple websites that are hosted with S3 using CloudFront in us-east-1. If there is an outage in that region, I want to reroute traffic from those UIs to a website hosted with S3 using CloudFront in another region (just a basic error page, all UIs from us-east-1 need to be rerouted to the same one error page in the new region).

After doing research, I am seeing a lot of documentation for Route 53 DNS Failover handling. However, we don't use Route 53 for traffic routing, so I don't think these solutions apply for this particular problem. Does anyone have any advice on possible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CloudFront's Origin Groups feature, you can group the two S3 endpoints and configure the criteria for when CloudFront should failover to the secondary origin (e.g., 500-504 error). When you create your cache behavior, you'll use the Origin Group as your origin. Details: [Optimizing high availability with CloudFront origin failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html)

Comment: And that will work even if there is an outage in the region that houses the Origin Group?

Comment: If your primary origin fails, Origin Groups ensure traffic will failover to your secondary origin. If there is an issue with a specific POP, traffic will reroute to another POP nearby. Once the traffic arrives at that POP, the Origin Group will be evaluated.

Comment: Do you know if using Lambda@Edge to route traffic be an option?